# Get value after hash with Jquery BBQ

Tags: jquery, jquery-bbq

I'm using Jquery BBQ as I want to get the value after a hash in a url. So I have:

```
            var url = $(this).attr('href');

            console.log(jQuery.deparam.fragment(url));
```

When I explore the log I see:

```
Object
131: undefined
__proto__: Object
__defineGetter__: function __defineGetter__() { [native code] }
```

Etc Etc.

The number 131 is the value after the hash I want, I just can't seem to get at it (I'm pretty new to Jquery). So how can I get at the value, in this case 131? This is probably very easy...

Comment: did you try with `jQuery.param.fragment(url)` instead of `jQuery.deparam.fragment(url)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [jQuery BBQ documentation](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-bbq/docs/files/jquery-ba-bbq-js.html):

> *`jQuery.deparam.fragment( [ url ] [, coerce ] )`*
>
> Parse the fragment (hash) from a URL or
>   the current window.location, deserializing it **into an object**,
>   optionally coercing numbers, booleans, null and undefined values.
>
> **Returns:** (Object) An object representing the deserialized params string.

so if you just want the entire fragment as a string you can use:

> *`jQuery.param.fragment( [url] )`*
>
> Retrieve the fragment (hash) from a URL or
>   if no arguments are passed, the current window.location.
>
> **Returns:** (String) The parsed fragment (hash) string, with any leading “#”
>   removed.